# How to prove that the vectors of the Krylov space of A are linearly independent if A is nonsingular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\mathbf{K}$ is a Krylov matrix.
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{K}&= \left[ \begin{array}{ccccc}
  \mathbf{b} & \mathbf{A}\mathbf{b} & \mathbf{A}^2\mathbf{b} & \cdots &  \mathbf{A}^{N-1}\mathbf{b} \end{array} \right]^T.
\end{align}

How to prove that the vectors of the Krylov space of $\bf A$ are linearly independent if $\bf A$ is nonsingular?

Comment: They don't have to be. For example if ${\bf A} = k{\bf I}$ then they will all be parallell.

Comment: Another counter-example is any rotation matrix in ND leaving say $m>0$ dimensions unchanged and rotating the rest amongst each other. The only variation happening will be the one in the planes of rotation so there will be a non-zero dimensional subspace which will always be linearly dependent.

Comment: One thing that I think would ensure linear independence is that all eigenvalues have distinct modulus ( absolute value ).

Comment: I agree with you. In fact, this question is come from the book:
(Emanuele Curotto) Stochastic Simulations of Clusters: Quantum Methods in Flat and Curved Spaces, CRC press Taylor & Francis group ISBN 9781420082258 (September 2009).

This question is the Exercises-3 on page 218.

Comment: But how to prove it if all eigenvalues have distinct modulus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In general this is not true**, for example ${\bf A} = k{\bf I}$ or a rotation matrix in 3D where vector projected along the the axis of rotation will never change and therefore always be linearly dependent. More generally any linear operator projecting on a specific non-zero dimensional subspace and having any arbitrary non-singular transform on the rest of the space, the vectors mentioned will not be linearly independent.

These are usually the cases in which Krylov subspace methods will converge **faster**.

---

But for example if all eigenvalues have distinct modulus, then the eigenspace must be simple and the matrix must be diagonalizable. Then each eigenvector (let us call them $\bf v$) will be scaled so we can write $${\bf A}^n{\bf b} = \sum_{\forall k} {\lambda_k}^n (\xi_k{\bf v}_k)$$

Since the ${\bf v}_k$ by definition must be linearly independent, the $\lambda_k$ are distinct and the monomial functions are linearly independent, we are done. This usually means we need to investigate larger parts of the space (more iterations) which makes convergence become **slower**.

---

Another way to maybe easier realize this is to write the coefficients of the vectors into a matrix:

$$\left[\begin{array}{lllll}\xi_1&\xi_2&\xi_3&\xi_4&\cdots\\\xi_1\lambda_1&\xi_2\lambda_2&\xi_3\lambda_3&\xi_4\lambda_4&\cdots\\\xi_1{\lambda_1}^2&\xi_2{\lambda_2}^2&\xi_3{\lambda_3}^2&\xi_4{\lambda_4}^2&\cdots\\\xi_1{\lambda_1}^3&\xi_2{\lambda_2}^3&\xi_3{\lambda_3}^3&\xi_4{\lambda_4}^3&\cdots\\\xi_1{\lambda_1}^4&\xi_2{\lambda_2}^4&\xi_3{\lambda_3}^4&\xi_4{\lambda_4}^4&\cdots\end{array}\right]$$

If these $\lambda_k$ are distinct (and our $\xi_k \neq 0$), what happens if we try to row-reduce?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand well. \\ Assume n=1, then
$${\bf A}{\bf b} = \sum_{\forall k} {\lambda_k} {\bf v}_k$$
$${\bf A}^{-1}{\bf A}{\bf b} = \sum_{\forall k} {\lambda_k} {\bf A}^{-1}{\bf v}_k$$
$${\bf b} = \sum_{\forall k} {\lambda_k} {\bf A}^{-1}{\bf v}_k= \sum_{\forall k} {\lambda_k} {\lambda_k}^{-1}{\bf v}_k=\sum_{\forall k} {\bf v}_k$$.
What's this mean?

Comment: Yes that will be one of the vectors spanning the Krylov sub-space. What about it?

Comment: But my problem is:
If all eigenvalues of ${\bf A}$ have distinct modulus, for any vector ${\bf b}$, at least ${\bf b}$ is not an eigenvector of ${\bf A}$.

How to prove that the vectors of the Krylov space of ${\bf K}$ are linearly independent?

Comment: If ${\bf b}={\bf v}_k$. It is seen clearly the vectors of ${\bf K}$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: There are several k, you sum over them.

Comment: Thanks very much, in fact, I cannot understand why you have 
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{b} = \sum_{m=1}^{M} v_m.
 \end{align}.

This is my understand:

Assuming $\mathbf{A}$ is a $M\times M$ matrix with $M$ distinct eigenvalues.
For any vector $\mathbf{b}$ ($\mathbf{b}$ is not an eigenvector of $\mathbf{A}$), we have
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{b} = \sum_{m=1}^{M} \xi_m v_m,
 \end{align}
where at least two elements of $\xi_m$ are not equal to 0.
Then
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A}^n\mathbf{b} &= \sum_{m=1}^{M} \xi_m \lambda_m^n \mathbf{v}_m.
 \end{align}

Comment: Considering $n=M$, the coefficients matrix is a square matrix and can be written as:
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{C}&= \left[ \begin{array}{ccccc}
 \xi_1 & \xi_1 \lambda_1 & \cdots & \xi_1 \lambda_1^n \\
 \xi_2 & \xi_2 \lambda_2 & \cdots & \xi_2 \lambda_2^n \\
  \vdots &  \vdots &  \ddots &  \vdots\\
 \xi_n & \xi_1 \lambda_n & \cdots & \xi_n \lambda_n^n \\
 \end{array} \right]^T.
\end{align}
Clearly, if there exist any $\xi_m=0$, then $\det(\mathbf{C})=0$, and $\mathbf{A}^n\mathbf{b}$ cannot be ensured linear independent.

What is wrong?

Comment: So, my conclusion is that if and only if $\xi_m \neq 0$, $\mathbf{A}^n\mathbf{b}$ can be linear independent. How do you think?

Comment: The $\xi_m$ are dependent on $\bf b$. Take the matrix $[2,0;0,1]$ and the vector ${\bf b}=[1;0]$. $\xi$ for vector $[0;1]$ will be 0. But is dependent on $\bf b$. The question in general did not make any assumption on $\bf b$. It was rather what would ensure the proposition to hold **regardless of which b is chosen**.

Comment: Accidentally having $\bf b$ point exactly in such a direction. Should never happen in any real interesting use case. But I agree, I will add $\xi$s to my matrix.